# Parse results from database table to a generic collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a method in Java that parses some data from a database

```
ArrayList<Object> nodeList = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void parseResults() throws SQLException, ListEmptyException, NoRecognisableCharacterException{
//        parses records from a query. ONLY ONE COLUMN
    while(getResultSet().next()){    
        for(int i = 1; i <= getNumberOfColumns(); i++){
            switch(getColumnType()){
//According to the datatype, I call the proper method get[DataType] of resultSet
                case 0:throw new ListEmptyException();
                case 4:nodeList.add(getResultSet().getInt(i));break;
                case 12:nodeList.add(getResultSet().getString(i).trim());break;
                default:throw new NoRecognisableCharacterException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was told not to use `ArrayList<Object>` to store data of different type. I have to create an entity that parses the appropriate datatype instead. I don't want to overload the method for every single datatype (there are plenty) neither create separate classes that just change a single `get[DataType]` method, nor have that `switch` loop inside `for` loop, nor have multible instances of nodeList according to datatype. Is there a way to make that method work for every datatype? Should generics do in that case? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea but the proper way to handle/parse different data from the DB is to use separate classes for different data loaded from different tables. The over-unification here defeats the purpose and does not help nor make your code clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your resultset object in a class like this:

```
public class ObjectWrapper implements Wrapper {
    private Object wrappedObject;

    public ObjectWrapper(Object wrappedObject) {
        this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> paramClass) {
        return (T) wrappedObject;
    }

    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return paramClass.isInstance(wrappedObject);
    }

    public static Wrapper wrap(ResultSet rs, int column, int columnType) throws SQLException {
        if (columnType == 0) {
            return new EmptyListExceptionWrapper();
        } else {
            return new ObjectWrapper(rs.getObject(column));
        }
    }
}
```

and a class to manage exceptions:

```
public class EmptyListExceptionWrapper implements Wrapper {
    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> paramClass) throws SQLException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> paramClass) throws SQLException {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you have an

```
ArrayList<Wrapper> wrapper = new ArrayList<Wrapper>;
```

Your code will be:

```
while(getResultSet().next()){    
    for(int i = 1; i <= getNumberOfColumns(); i++){
        wrappers.add(ObjectWrapper.wrap(getResultSet(), i, getColumnType()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!! But, it returns names like `dataBaseConnection.ObjectWrapper@179d3b25`...how am I supposed to fix it?

Comment: You should override toString method.

Comment: All those Wrapper classes are completely new to me...would you be so kind as to tell me exactly how to override `toString()` method to this?

Comment: `@Override
public String toString() {    return wrappedObject.toString();
}`